# Load and compile external Handlebars templates?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to use Handlebars to power a kiosk unit that is showing local HTML files. These files use Javascript to fetch remote content, and Handlebars controls the template/output.

What I want to do is keep the Handlebars template(s) in their own directory, and when interacting with buttons (links) - inject these templates into the page, then fill the content with an AJAX response.

I have everything working except for the template output:

Link example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Kiosk.history(); return false;">History</a></li>
```

In application.js:

```
history: function() {

    var source;

    Zepto.ajax({
      url: 'templates/history.handlebars',
      dataType: 'html',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data, status, response) {
        source = data;
        var template    = Handlebars.compile(response.responseText);

        var context = {
          title: 'Static Title (to be replaced)'
        };

        $('#main-content').html(template(context));
      }
    });
```

The handlebars file:

```
<div class="row" id="history">
  <div class="large-10 columns large-offset-1">
    <script id="hb-history" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>{{ title }}</h2>

      {{ body }}
    </script>should have a template here
  </div>
</div>
```

I seem to be missing something because the #main-content div is never updated with the dynamic template, only outputs 'should be a template here'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, was right in front of me. Script tag in the template is not needed.